# AVL: Right rotation, updating heights

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

I am reading a tutorial in AVL trees https://www.programiz.com/dsa/avl-tree
In the implementation of right rotation
https://www.programiz.com/dsa/avl-tree    # Function to perform right rotation

```py
def rightRotate(self, z):
    y = z.left
    T3 = y.right
    y.right = z
    z.left = T3
    z.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(z.left),
                       self.getHeight(z.right))
    y.height = 1 + max(self.getHeight(y.left),
                       self.getHeight(y.right))
    return y
```

I do not understand why we need to change only these heights.

For example here:
[image]

Both 8 , 9 and 11 changed heights but according to the implementation only 9's and 11's heights will be informed as I understand.

Comment: NB: a better AVL algorithm will manage a balance factor, and *not* a height. This way no updates are needed on the path to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left subtree and the right subtree of the node in your example (node 8) will not be affected by the right rotation، and so the height of that node will not need to change. (Because the height of a node is equal to 1 + max(height of left subtree, height of right subtree)).

Comment: I think I confused depth with height. 8 remains a leaf, therefore has height 1 right?

Comment: @tonythestark Yeah, you're absolutely right. I think whenever you are confused checking the definition would help a lot.